# "To suggest/To propose" something in Spanish

Tags: traducción, verbos

I'm writing an email where I'd like to say:

> "I **suggest** we meet at the same time and place, only change the day to Friday."

The verb offered by translation software is **sugerir**. In the definition for sugerir, **proponer** (to propose) comes up as a synonym. So 2 questions:

1) For my example above, which would be most appropriate for a casual email or conversation? The below was offered by translation software:

> "Sugiero que nos encontremos al mismo tiempo y lugar, sólo cambiar el día al viernes."

2) In general, are **sugerir** and **proponer** used like their English counterparts? Is one more commonly used than the other?

Thank you!

Comment: In the sample sentence, "proponer" sounds much better to my ear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ESPAÑOL - English (follows)**

"Sugerir"/"proponer" y "sugerencia"/"propuesta", como en inglés "*to suggest*"/"*to propose*" y "*suggestion*"/"*proposal*", pueden emplearse del mismo modo en ciertos casos, aunque son sutilmente diferentes. Pueden equivaler a "recomendar" y "recomendación, como en inglés "*to recommend*" y "*recommendation*".

En el caso de tu pregunta, puedes usar ambas formas indistintamente:

- **Sugiero** que nos encontremos en el mismo lugar y hora, cambiando únicamente el día al viernes.
- **Propongo** que nos encontremos en el mismo lugar y hora, cambiando únicamente el día al viernes.

En general, "sugerir" significa lo mismo que "proponer", aunque también puede significar "evocar" (traer algo a la memoria) o "dejar entrever" (como en los tejidos transparentes).

"Proponer" o "hacer una propuesta" suele implicar un mayor detalle que sugerir. Cuando se sugiere algo se espera que sean considerados los pros y contras para tomar una decisión, aunque no es condición indispensable que dichas consideraciones vayan incluidas en la sugerencia. Cuando se hace una propuesta, normalmente se incluye un análisis previo de los pros y los contras, de las repercusiones, de las posibles alternativas, del coste o el ahorro (cuando proceda)...

Tal como [comenta Sergio Velásquez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13343/to-suggest-to-propose-something-in-spanish/13344?noredirect=1#comment16072_13344), "*proponer*" también es usado en el contexto de una proposición [matrimonial], directamente o insinuada, aunque entonces no estamos hablando de una "propuesta" sino una "proposición".

Me propuso matrimonio.
Se me propuso [en matrimonio].

---

**ENGLISH**

"*Sugerir*"/"*proponer*" and "*sugerencia*"/"*propuesta*", as in English "to suggest"/"to propose" and "suggestion"/"proposal", can be used the same way in certain cases, but are subtly different. They may equal to "*recomendar*" and "*recommendación*", as in English "to recommend" and "recommendation".

In the case of your question, you can use both forms interchangeably:

- **Sugiero** que nos encontremos en el mismo lugar y hora, cambiando únicamente el día al viernes.
- **Propongo** que nos encontremos en el mismo lugar y hora, cambiando únicamente el día al viernes.

In general, "*sugerir*" means the same as "*proponer*", although it can also mean "*evocar*" (to evoke, to bring something to mind) or "dejar entrever" (hinting, as in transparent fabrics).

"*Proponer*" or "*hacer una propuesta*" usually implies greater detail than "*sugerir"*. When something is suggested it is expected to be considered the pros and cons for making a decision, although it is not necessarily provided that such considerations will be included in the suggestion. When a proposal is made, usually it is included a preliminary analysis of the pros and cons, the impact of possible alternatives, cost or cost savings (if applicable)...

As [Sergio Velásquez commented](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13343/to-suggest-to-propose-something-in-spanish/13344?noredirect=1#comment16072_13344), "*proponer*" is also used in the context of a marriage proposal (*proposición* [matrimonial]), directly or hinting, although then we are not talking about a "*propuesta*" but a "*proposición*".

*Me propuso matrimonio*. He proposed me to marry.
*Se me propuso [en matrimonio]*. I was proposed [marriage] by him.

Comment: Sugerir también tiene (para mí al menos) un mayor grado de recomendación.  Puedo hacer varias propuestas (sin recomendar ninguna), pero probablemente solo sugeriré una de ellas (la que recomiendo)

Comment: Es posible que sea algo un poco subjetivo, pero se me ocurre que podemos encontrar "sugerencia de presentación" (por ejemplo en una lata de atún) como algo informal, sin análisis de detalles, y sería raro encontrar "propuesta de presentación". Otro ejemplo: "te sugiero que consultes con el especialista"; ¿dirías "te propongo que consultes con el especialista"?

Comment: Para la respuesta puntual a la pregunta, es claro que no es fuerte la diferencia entre proponer y sugerir pero hay otro uso que no sé si es común en españa pero en algunas partes de latinoamérica se acostumbra decir: _se me propuso_ o _voy a hacerle la propuesta_ haciendo referencia a solicitar la mano en matrimonio.

Comment: @blassoriano «Te propongo que consultes...» no creo que diría nunca, sin duda sugerir me sale mucho más natural.